# How to know if an href download failed using <a> tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to download a file using HTML a tag

```
 var a = document.createElement("a");
 a.href = "floor.laz";
 a.click();
```

I get this error:

[image]

After the browser started the download.
Is there anyway to know from the code when an error like this happens?

Comment: In Chrome by pressing F12 you can get to DevTools and errors are listed in Console tab

Comment: have a reporter on the server. Which checks if the whole file is downloaded. The trigger for checking can be sent when the user clicks on the link.

Comment: Why use a link when you can use ajax and catch every error possible?

Comment: I would think you can use the HTTP server response code. And like @Bast advices is to use Ajax.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987349/is-there-a-way-to-get-http-status-code-name-using-js-and-angularjs